# How do I test if a variable is within a group of values?

Tags: c

I am running a loop which tests whether or not a typed character was a letter. I want something like the "IN" function from sql or a way of providing similar functionality - something other than (variable == 'A' || 'a' || 'B' || 'b' || 'C' || 'c'...) of course. An example of what I mean using pseudo code would be:

```
char c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
      if (c == 'upper or lower case letter')
      {
          runthis();
      }

      else
      {
           dothis();
      }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `isalpha()` or similar is the way to go. But, if your input can be anything and your `char`s can be negative, remember to cast the value to `unsigned char`. `/*signed*/ char name="Günther", *p=name; while (p) if (isalpha((unsigned char)*p)) ... p++ ...`

Comment: Thanks everyone! You're all my hero :D

Comment: When your range isn't "nice", you can use `if (strchr("ACGTacgt", c))`

Answer (score 2):

How about calling the `isalpha()` function?

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
      if (isalpha((unsigned)c))
      {
          runthis();
      }

      else
      {
           dothis();
      }
}
```

Make sure that you've included the `<ctype.h>` header! This header includes other similar functions like `islower()` and `isupper()`, which tell you whether a character is a lower-case or upper-case letter, respectively, and `isdigit()`, which tells you whether a character is a digit.

Comment: getchar returns an int.  c should be an int so it can match EOF.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `isalpha` function from the `ctype.h` header file. See the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/isalpha/) here.

Usage:

```
#include <ctype.h>

...

if (isalpha(c))
{
    runthis();
}
else
{
    dothat();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`isalpha()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/locale/isalpha/):

```
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", isalpha('x'));
    printf("%d\n", isalpha('5'));
}
```

There are several functions in this family, such as `isupper()`, `islower()`, `isalnum()`, `isdigit()`, `isspace()`.

Answer (score 0):

C has a function called [`isalpha`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/isalpha/) which handles your case.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing the question in the *title* (but less optimal for *this* case where the range is continuous).

---

A more general answer for integer types (`char`,`short`,`int`,`enum`,...)  is to use `switch`/`case` and take advantage of the fall-through behavior:

```
switch (foo) {
case SOME_VALUE:
case ANOTHER_VALUE:
case COMMON_VALUE:
case NOT_SO_COMMON_VALUE:
   dowhatever(foo);
   break;
default:
   dotheotherthing(foo);
   break;
}
```

You can, of course, wrap the case up in a function to make your own `iscategory()` function (parallel to the standard library functions `isspace()`, `isalpha()`, etc). Just `return` for the right values rather than calling on...

Comment: @Michael: A generic function name template, where `category` can be replaced with whatever logical category of thing identity that you're checking for.

Answer (score 0):

There's a whole group of *character classification functions*. Their names are quite self explanatory:

```
int isalnum(int c) // Equivalent to isalpha(c) || isdigit(c)
int isalpha(int c) // Letters
int isblank(int c) // Space or tab
int iscntrl(int c) // Control character
int isdigit(int c) // Digit
int isgraph(int c) // Printable character that's not space
int islower(int c) // Lowercase letter
int isprint(int c) // Printable characters including space
int ispunct(int c) // Printable characters except space and alphanumeric
int isspace(int c) // Checks for whitespace characters according to the locale
int isupper(int c) // Uppercase letters
int isxdigit(int c) // Hexadecimal digits
```

You can read about it in the [C11 standard 7.4.1](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.4.1)

If none of the above suits your needs, you can create your own with `strchr()`. Example:

```
// Check if c is a lowercase vowel
char lcvowel[] = "aeiouy";
if(strchr(lcvowel, c)) {
```

If you're using such a function a lot, create a wrapper:

```
int islowervowel(int c) {
    return schr("aeiouy", c);
}
```

Posix has one function not listed above

```
int isascii(int c) // 7-bit ascii character set
```

I guess the reason it is not included in standard C is that C does not presume ascii encoding. Or maybe they just did not find it useful enough. Nevertheless, you can read about it (and all the others) here: https://linux.die.net/man/3/isascii

Answer (score -1):

I can think of two quick ways.

First, if all the characters are in a single range, you can compare against the boundaries of the range.

```
if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
```

The other method is to use a lookup table that is prefilled with boolean values for each character to declare whether it has the desired property.

Note that this answer is for the general case - there are existing library functions for many specific cases, such as determining an alpha character.

Comment: Of course, now some pedantic person will come along and point out that the C standard doesn't guarantee that the English alphabet maps to a contiguous range of character values.  Oh wait...

Comment: @Oli, I anticipated that comment and specifically used the word "if".

Comment: Ah, but you didn't specify *which* range! A-Z occupy a contiguous range in an english alphabet, but it's not given that their representational values in some C implementation will occupy a contiguous range.  Also, it's problematic with non-C locales.

Comment: @zvrba, the second method I describe works for the non-contiguous case.